# Installing failover cluster with windows 2003 server

Tags: virtualization, virtual-machine, windows-2003-webserver, windows-clustering

I am a beginner in clustering and virtualization stuffs. Can anyone tell me whether can we have both active node and passive node  as virtual machine in failover cluster.

Any help please!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you're about to get into MSCS, I'd strongly recommend looking at the offerings in Win2k8, as things have improved drastically.  However, if you stick with Win2k3, yes, you can cluster on VMware.  VMware have even published a whitepaper - Google "vmware mscs white paper".